# How can i get text from text field and place text in another text field in android

Tags: android, forms

Hi
I am new to android,
How can i get text from a text field and store into variable and how can i place text in a text field.
Whati mean is, in C# or Flex or other languages we have functions or properties like if there is some text field txtName, and we do txtName.text or txtName.getText(), it returns text, and if we do like txtName.text ="abc", it assigns a value to it,
but i have not found any thing like that in android yet, please help me.

Regards
Atif

Answer (score 0):

Use **getText()** and **setText()** method of TextView.
For example:

```
TextView tf=new TextView(this);
 tf.setText("Hello");
 String s=(String) tf.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first get ids for the EditTexts:

```
 EditText et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text1);  //replace edit_text1 with your id
 EditText et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text2);  //replace edit_text2 with your id
 et2.setText(et1.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming in your XML layout your EditText has the id text you can get it by

```
final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
String textInEditText = text.getText().toString();
```

or you can set it by:

```
text.setText("Some text");
```

You can find more information about [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) and [general Android Development](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) (e.g. what is a layout?) in the normal guides.